# pViewports is always UNUSED

Tags: vulkan

I have enabled all verification layers and am *error and warning free* and should be able to render a colored triangle. However, currently all I am seeing is a cleared screen (black) or an empty screen (grey) depending on the machine I am running on.

Upon further inspection it seems in my call to vkCreateGraphicsPipelines the pViewports and pScissors are always set to UNUSED even though I passed in values. I do not have dynamicState and the counts are both one.

Am I missing a flag or is my binding flawed?

Code snippet:

```
Thread 0, Frame 0:
vkCreateGraphicsPipelines(device, pipelineCache, createInfoCount, pCreateInfos, pAllocator, pPipelines) returns VkResult VK_SUCCESS (0):
    device:                         VkDevice = 00000000056FD350
    pipelineCache:                  VkPipelineCache = 0000000000000000
    createInfoCount:                uint32_t = 1
    pCreateInfos:                   const VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo* = 000000000566BB38
        pCreateInfos[0]:                const VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo = 000000000566BB38:
            sType:                          VkStructureType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_CREATE_INFO (28)
            pNext:                          const void* = NULL
        ...
            pViewportState:                 const VkPipelineViewportStateCreateInfo* = 000000000725A920:
                sType:                          VkStructureType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VIEWPORT_STATE_CREATE_INFO (22)
                pNext:                          const void* = NULL
                flags:                          VkPipelineViewportStateCreateFlags = 0
                viewportCount:                  uint32_t = 1
                pViewports:                     const VkViewport* = UNUSED
                scissorCount:                   uint32_t = 1
                pScissors:                      const VkRect2D* = UNUSED
```

Debugging prints:

```
 Pipeline_Info.pViewportState.pScissors before assign = 0
 Pipeline_Info.pViewportState.pViewports before assign = 0
 Pipeline_Info.pViewportState.pScissors after assign = 2350856
 Pipeline_Info.pViewportState.pViewports after assign = 2348296
 vkCreateGraphicsPipelines call result = 0
```

Full API Dump (see line 2107):
https://pastebin.com/MmXUBnk0

Full code (for those who are curious - see line 791):
https://github.com/AdaDoom3/AdaDoom3/blob/master/Engine/neo-engine-renderer.adb

Comment: Don't know much about ada, but that source looks fine. I tested with my own examples too, passing viewport and scissor at pipeline creation time instead of dynamic states and it works fine. As for the flags: Right now there are no flags that can be passed to the viewport create info structure, so 0 is always correct.
The output of vktrace may be wrong, so can you try clearing with different colors and make the viewport/scissor smaller? That way you can see if viewport and scissor are ignored.

Comment: No dice, what would be some decent values to set it to? - I tried 300.0 and 300.0 for the extent but it is still unused. I am going to try doing the dynamic mode later today and see if it picks it up then...

Comment: I get the same report with a working app. Probably bug in the layer. Your problem is probably elsewhere.

Comment: That would be disappointing - I am running out of leads at this point. I have no idea what to do. For the record on my desktop machine I am able to make the clear color whatever I want, but it will not show on my laptop - just the standard grey screen.

Comment: As an alternative to vktrace you could take a look at [RenderDoc](http://www.renderdoc.org) which is the Vulkan debugger of choice for many (including me). It has a pipeline state visualization that lists viewports and scissors of the currently bound pipeline ([screenshot](https://www.saschawillems.de/images/renderdoc_pipelinestate.png)). If you see the viewport and scissor there, then (as @krOoze noted) something else might be wrong.

Comment: @SaschaWillems I am seeing an overlay and I am trying to follow the docs, but nothing is showing in renderdoc window after capturing frames or closing the app. I can post the exe to my github with debugging on if you want to take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wanted to confirm: The `UNUSED` is definitely a `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_api_dump` layer bug.
There is basically `if(false) ... else print UNUSED` in the code.
UPDATE: Issue [fix PR](https://github.com/LunarG/VulkanTools/pull/256).

So that is a dead end. But you found a bug in the Vulkan ecosystem which is a good thing too...

As for your rendering problem, in several places you have 1x1 render target (e.g. in `vkCmdBeginRenderPass`), so there would be not much to see. I think Windows usually does this (initially creating 0x0 window) and then you have to react to a resize event.

Comment: Ok, should I mark this as the answer? I am hesitant to do that should this question get the attention of someone who can help.

Comment: @RWilco8 You made your Q in large part about this, so I thought I offer it as a (partial?) answer. On SO **you** are partly the moderator. Depends on your taste if you want to close this (and potentially make a new Q), or if you would rather edit this Q (with this `UNUSED` assumption of yours being a dead end your Q bacame bit broad unless you supply some new information).

Comment: @RWilco8 Adding my suspicion, what the problem might be based on scanning over the api_dump.

Comment: Ok, I am marking this question as answered and making a new about renderdoc.. hope I am not spamming [Vulkan] too much..